# LoopbackJS - Tokens for user invites

Tags: authentication, model, loopbackjs

I'm using loopback as the API server for my application. I'm building a social like network, where it's required to invite users via email. In order to associate the invitee with the inviter, I want the inviter to create a 'request token' associated with his userId, which then is sent via email in a format like this: domain.com/register?token=XXXXXX

The built-in Access Token model seems perfect for this purpose as a base model used so the idea is to create a new model "RequestToken" inheriting from the AccessToken model, however, the new model is then used for authentication purposes as well, which I don't want.

Following are my config files. It's worth mentioning that the below seen "Customer" model is extending Loopbacks "User" Model.

**/server/model-config.json:**

```
"_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "loopback/common/models",
      "loopback/server/models",
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ],
    "mixins": [
      "loopback/common/mixins",
      "loopback/server/mixins",
      "../node_modules/loopback-ds-timestamp-mixin",
      "../common/mixins",
      "./mixins"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false,
    "relations": {
      "user": {
        "type": "belongsTo",
        "model": "Customer",
        "foreignKey": "userId"
      }
    }
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false,
    "options": {
      "strictObjectIDCoercion": true
    }
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Email": {
    "dataSource": "mail",
    "public": false
  },
  "Customer": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
  "Friend": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
  "Memory": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  },
  "RequestToken": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true
  }
}
```

Under "Customer" I've also tried to include:

```
"relations": {
      "accessTokens": {
        "type": "hasMany",
        "model": "AccessToken",
        "foreignKey": "userId",
        "options": {
          "disableInclude": true
        }
      }
    }
```

**common/customer.json**

```
    {
      "name": "Customer",
      "base": "User",
      "idInjection": true,
      "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
      },
      "mixins": {
        "TimeStamp": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "firstName": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        },
        "lastName": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": true
        },
        "dob": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "validations": [],
      "relations": {
        "accessTokens": {
          "type": "hasMany",
          "model": "AccessToken",
          "foreignKey": "userId",
          "options": {
            "disableInclude": true
          }
        },
        "requestTokens": {
          "type": "hasMany",
          "model": "RequestToken",
          "foreignKey": "userId",
          "options": {
            "disableInclude": true
          }
        }
      },
      "acls": [
        {
          "accessType": "EXECUTE",
          "principalType": "ROLE",
          "principalId": "$owner",
          "permission": "ALLOW"
        },
        {
          "accessType": "*",
          "principalType": "ROLE",
          "principalId": "$everyone",
          "permission": "DENY"
        }
      ],
      "methods": {}
    }
```

**common/request-token.json**

```
{
  "name": "RequestToken",
  "base": "AccessToken",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Customer",
      "foreignKey": "ownerId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Summary:
How can I create a new "RequestToken" model, extending Loopbacks "AccessToken" model, but keep using the built-in AccessToken model for authentication etc.? Is it possible at all? As soon as I take the line `'"base": "AccessToken"'` out of the request-token.json file, all authentication method work again.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found a solution for this. Within server.js I needed to tell the app to use the AccessToken model.

**server.js**

```
...
app.use(loopback.token({
  model: app.models.accessToken,
}));
...
```

I've added it just after

```
const app = loopback();
```

The docs refer to it to use it for authentication via cookies in the LB2 docs.
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Making-authenticated-requests.html
I'm using Loopback3. Within the LB3 docs, they do not mention this way anymore, so if there is another solution, happy to change the accepted answer.

Cheers